# Is there any recommended HTTP proxy software?

Tags: http, proxy

I use the macOS, and I can set the HTTP proxy in there:

[image]

is there any recommended way to set up the HTTP proxy?

such as I can set up it in my macOS, then I input the `127.0.0.1:port` there with the username and password.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, there are many HTTP proxy softwares.

The representative ones are:

[Squid](https://github.com/squid-cache/squid)

[node-http-proxy](https://github.com/http-party/node-http-proxy)

[HTTP-Proxy-Servlet](https://github.com/mitre/HTTP-Proxy-Servlet)